# How to binary replace values in columns based on value in it

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, replace

I have a dataframe:

```
v1   v2  v3
x    b   x
o    x   x
x    x   x
b    b   b
g    b   g
x    g   x
```

I want to replace values in columns with 1 and 0. 1 if value is equal x (and type must be changed too), 0 if it anything else (and type must be changed too). How could i do that?

I try this, but it doesnt work:

```
for i in range(3):
    df.iloc[:,i].replace([0,1],['b','x'],inplace=True).astype("int")
```

And I don't know how to write part with 0 for anything besides of "x"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick (to write) and dirty using `.applymap()` on each element:

```
df.applymap(lambda el: 1 if el in ["x", "b"] else 0)
```

Vectorized method:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.isin(["x", "b"]), dtype="int", columns=df.columns)
```

**Result**

```
   v1  v2  v3
0   1   1   1
1   0   1   1
2   1   1   1
3   1   1   1
4   0   1   0
5   1   0   1
```

The `dtypes` are `int64`

Comment: for the vectorized method, another approach is `(df == "x").astype(np.int64)`

Comment: Yeah if you don't need the column names, that is indeed the way to go.

Comment: Oops, I didn't realize the column names were reset. Thanks.

Comment: And if i want it be x and b i should write it this way pd.DataFrame(df.values == "x" or "b", dtype="int", columns=df.columns) ?

Comment: In that case, use `df.isin(["x", "b"])`. The answer is updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do the following instead of an `applymap` -

```
(df=='x').astype(int)
```

```
    v1  v2  v3
0   1   0   1
1   0   1   1
2   1   1   1
3   0   0   0
4   0   0   0
5   1   0   1
```

If you want to check both 'x' and 'b', then use `.isin()` method -

```
(df.isin(('x','b'))).astype(int)
```

```
    v1  v2  v3
0   1   1   1
1   0   1   1
2   1   1   1
3   1   1   1
4   0   1   0
5   1   0   1
```